# Angular withCredentials not Working for GET

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cookies, cors

I have an angular app and a spring boot backend. I have to send the cookies from the browser to the backend.

Now the problem: When I use `ng serve` everything works as expected. The cookies are send and could be processed by the backend. When I build my application with `ng build --no-aot` the Browser is not Sendig any cookies.

Note: We are in an Cross Origen Setup.

Here is my Spring Cors Configuration. I explicitly defined my Origin. I am not useing `*` as config:

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
  CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
  corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
  corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("http://127.0.0.1:8080");
  corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"));
  corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("origin");
  corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("content-type");
  corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("accept");
  corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("ct-remote-user");
  corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("shared-secret");
  corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("cookie");
  UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new 
  UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
  urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
  return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource); 
}
```

My Http Client in my angular app uses `{withCredentials: true}` as option:

```
get(requestPath: string, params?: HttpParams, responseType?): Observable<any> {
    const options = {headers: this.getDefaultHeaders(), withCredentials: true, params, responseType: responseType};
    return this.httpClient.get(requestPath, options);
}
```

When I inspect the Requests in my browser the Preflight Request send the Following:

```
OPTIONS /pathToRessource HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9084
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

And my Server responds with this:

```
Request-Id: fe605923-1f0f-40c7-bf5e-a575903df450
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 30 Dec 2020 10:18:16 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

So I would suggest that CORS is configured correctly. When I now send my GET-Request The cookie is not included in the request and the Server responds with 403 due to the missing Cookie Header (This is the right behaviour). Are there any suggestion what I am doing wrong? I searched for the problem bevor asking this question but all the solutions suggest configuring CORS corectly. I think this is the case here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In conclusion my error was that my backend services were deployed under route A and Frontend under route B. They both have different top level domains. The cookie I try to send not matches the top level domain of the service. Thats why it is not send.